# What is the best way to read the lines of dynamically generated file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-handling

I have a log file which gets dynamically populated by the second. I want to read the file (latest lines) and filter out if any exception. What is the best way to read the lines of dynamically generated file in Perl?

Comment: File::Tail? . . .

Comment: Do you require real time detection/reaction or low processing footprint?

Comment: `tail -f /path/log/file | egrep "filter1|filter2"`?

Answer (score 2):

See [How do I do a tail -f in perl?](https://perldoc.pl/perlfaq5#How-do-I-do-a-tail-f-in-perl?) in perlfaq5 and [`File::Tail`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail).